# Classical style bands/music with non-opera vocal singer

Tags: classical-music, identify-this-genre

I really like classical music with low number of instruments and I also like woman voice singing in calm, natural style (non-opera style). Does anyone here know for some band or music piece that combines those two elements?

Band/music assembly would be like:

- 1 woman voice
- Flute
- Cello
- Bassoon
- Clarinet
- Oboe

Something like:

- [Amy Nuttall - Scarborough Fair](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D7YDOhz7jxo)
- [Amy Nuttall - Greensleeves](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=33Ja6ZcdS8w)

Comment: Blackmore's Night may be a good example.

Comment: @TimSparrow: Yea they are ok, but not "classical" enough for me. :P

Comment: Do you have an example of a song like this that you like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classical music for small ensemble is called *[Chamber Music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chamber_music).*  It's typically instrumental, but there are compositions for what would be called "Voice with Chamber Ensemble."  This link gives several examples: https://www.talkclassical.com/12105-chamber-music-featuring-voice.html

Here are a couple links I found using that as a search term, but the vocals aren't quite as naturalistic as you're seeking.  Unfortunately the highly trained vocal approach you're calling "opera style" is the standard for classical music.

[Thy Dream](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=stTNHrPqKoI)
[Elegy for Voice, Flute and Piano](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WHTmg62R_UU)
[From the Japanese Poetry](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xeqh-hwS81U)

As @Angst identified, if you really want the naturalistic vocals, you'll probably have to go all the way back to the pre-classical era, to what's called "[Early Music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_music)".  Here's a good mix I found using the search term ["early music female vocal"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EsWubEZXE6w) (although it's really more "medieval-style" than actually authentic).

Finally, if you're not wedded to a classical style, you might enjoy female-fronted [New Age](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New-age_music) music like [Loreena McKennit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AIR5XPWK3Vk) and [Enya](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5yRgiXh2fP4) or even [Chamber Pop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chamber_pop) music like [San Fermin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ld81Y6Em3NM), [Girls in Trouble](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=il6FgcTz2M8) and [Regina Spektor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tHAhnJbGy9M).

Comment: Something between medieval vocals and classical chamber music is my jam. Something like: [Amy Nuttall - Greensleeves](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=33Ja6ZcdS8w) Loreena McKennit is quite nice choice too!

Comment: I think [Amy Nuttall - Scarborough Fair](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D7YDOhz7jxo) represents my kind of music.

Answer (score 2):

You could look into the career of [Jantina Noorman](http://www.folkworld.de/31/e/dutch.html), a singer from the (Dutch) folk tradition who crossed over into "early music" with her work with [Musica Reservata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musica_Reservata_(early_music_group)).

For example, [Music from the time of Christopher Columbus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tqAoaOttygo).

Comment: Nice find! Some of them really match OP description.